# How can I move massive buildings in-game in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there some way to move a massive building from underwater to above water in Minecraft? I suspect the answer is pistons, but how would I push the building more than one block? And would the water blocks covering the building stay on top of if after the building is out of water? How would I stop it after it is at surface level?

This will be on a private server, where I am admin. Bukkit will be used, in case someone knows a plugin to do this.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that pistons can only push a line of twelve blocks at a time, and unless your building is completely solid, would simply push the floor of any room up to meet the ceiling. Basically, pistons are not a good way to move a building.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't mind "cheating", the easiest way would most likely be using MCEdit or WorldEdit. If this building is *massive* like you say, it would take a very, very long time to move it above ground using pistons. If you really wanted to do this, though, you would put a piston under a block, activate it with a lever, place a block in the new empty space, and repeat. Unfortunately, since you are supposedly underwater, this would be very difficult.

However, I have done testing, and if you were to push a column of blocks up using a piston and one of them is a water source block, the water simply disappears.

**Edit:** Now that I see you're an admin on a Minecraft server, I'll give you WorldEdit instructions. To use [WorldEdit](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/edit-sec-admn-worldedit-4-6-world-editing-de-griefing-1000.62/), first install it on your server. Then use the `//wand` command to give yourself a Wooden Axe. Use this to left-click on the bottom-leftmost block of your building, and right-click on the top-rightmost block. This encloses your building in a "selection". From there, you can `//copy` and `//paste` it wherever you please.

Comment: Worldedit it is then. I am planning to make some sort of spectacle for my friends who will be watching me unveil my building, which is why I asked for ingame moving

Comment: Sounds cool! If you need more information on WorldEdit usage (it's an extremely powerful plugin), [here's the wiki](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit) dedicated to it.

Comment: Uhoh since my building will be underwater, won't the water be moved as well, creating a wall of water, like when moving water in mc edit?

Comment: I just ran a test, and doing a `//replace water air` before your `//copy` will get rid of all the water, leaving you with a water-less copy of your structure. (The non-water source blocks that the ocean above will create won't affect your copy.)

Comment: Oh yeah. I forgot about the layer if water above. Wow. I'll have to check, but my building might be >64 blocks tall, so it might not work

Comment: Why would your building being >64 blocks tall affect it? WorldEdit doesn't have restrictions on its selection sizes.

Comment: Isn't water level at 64 or so? This entire idea might not even work because part of the building might get cutoff because it goes past bedrock

Comment: Hmm. Well, try it and report back on how it goes. I'll try to help you further if for some reason this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Pistons can push pistons, as long as the ones that are being pushed are closed.

However, you'd be *much* better off using [WorldEdit](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit/Region_operations#Moving).

Answer (score 0):

you could use the mcedit nudge or copy

Comment: Can you expand on this? Your answer is a little brief.

Answer (score 0):

In 1.10 and above, you can use a [structure block](https://www.digminecraft.com/getting_started/structure_block_corner_mode.php) to effectively copy and paste a large region at once.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a clone command and it will move it like pistons, but faster and without work